# How to execute Adb shell commands from Xamarin.Android App

Tags: xamarin.android, device-policy-manager, device-owner, adb

I want to make my app Device owner using Device policy manager for which I need to execute following command:

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner {package_name}/{receiver_name}
```

This works find when emulator is running, and this command is hit from command line.

But I want to execute this programmatically, which I tried this way:

```
Java.Lang.Process process = Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(command);
process.WaitFor();
```

But this doesn't work. As per the docs, I found a method [ExecuteShellCommand](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.UiAutomation.ExecuteShellCommand/p/System.String/) under UiAutomation, but not sure how to use this method. Can anyone pls help?

Comment: What error did you get when you execute the command?

Comment: There's no error, but when I further check if device is owner, which this command should have executed, that returned false.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part is how your command is defined.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934376/execute-root-commands-and-read-output-xamarin) I got the following working

```
    Java.Lang.Process process = Runtime.GetRuntime()?.Exec(new string[] { "su", "-c", "echo test"});
    var result = process?.WaitFor();
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
```

where *echo test* is you actual command and *su -c* means substitute user and run the following command.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied
when targeting sdk version 29...

Comment: Is your device rooted? In most cases I'd say it has to be to work.
Try to unlock your device while trying to run this command. Does it promt you to grant permission?