# Execute Root Commands and read output Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, command, root, execute, su

I can't read the file from the root directory.
How to do it?
I use the command for reading

```
Java.Lang.Process suProcess =  Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new string[] { "su", "-c", "cat /data/misc/vpn/state" });
```

but how do I get an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The `Java.Lang.Process` class has some interesting `Streams` you will need to read from. `InputStream` and `ErrorStream`.

First of all, after you have created your process, you will need to wait for it. This can be done nicely with `.WaitForAsync()`. This will allow you to answer any dialogs etc. that usually come up when asking for root permissions.

When `.WaitForAsync()` returns it gives you an Exit Code. 0 means everything went well any other Exit Code means that there probably was an error.

In the case of Exit Code 0, you can probably read from the `InputStream` and get what you are looking for.

So you code would end up looking something like:

```cs
async Task<string> GetVpnStatus()
{
    var process = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new string[] { "su", "-c", "cat /data/misc/vpn/state" });
    var exitCode = await process.WaitForAsync();

    if (exitCode == 0)
    {
        using (var outputStreamReader = new StreamReader(process.InputStream))
            return await outputStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    if (process.ErrorStream != null)
    {
        using (var errorStreamReader = new StreamReader(process.ErrorStream))
            return await errorStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    return null;
}
```

The result of this will look something like

```
ppp0
10.0.0.42/32
0.0.0.0/0
105.112.3.1 123.234.12.55
```